# Materialzed view or normal view

Tags: oracle19c

We have a requirement of creating a view which is showing results after some processing the data on the table having almost 3 billion records. No joins just processing on one column and return the data. Still view is not performing well.

Will creating a materialized view be good idea on such a large table?

Or in any way we can improve the performance of the view.?

Thanks

Comment: Define "performance of the view".  A view doesn't have performance characteristics.  Queries against the view do.  Are you writing a query that returns 1 billion rows from the view?  Or 10 rows?  Does that query use an index on the underlying table to determine which rows to fetch?  How expensive is the "processing" you are referring to for the rows that are getting fetched by your query compared to the overall runtime of the query?

Comment: Yes that's correct I mean to say performance of the query only. We need to extract the records from the view from 1 row to millions based on the requirement after performing some calculation on a column. yes Index are implemented on the table and we are extracting data based on that column only.                                                                                                                                               Table fetch is taking 2vseconds and view is taking 45 seconds.

Comment: The performance of a query that selects 1 row will, presumably, be vastly different than the query that selects millions of rows.  Which of the two is actually the problematic query?  Posting queries and query plans will likely be a minimal requirement to get any sort of useful assistance.